# UIButton Height Increase Size Using AutoLayout with Different Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I have a fully functional app and I'm creating a new View Controller in Interface Builder with buttons and labels. I've laid out everything in the Interface Builder and used `AutoLayout` to make sure every component is in place. It's working very well on the iPhone 5s, but with the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, my `UIButton`s are not resizing it's height to adjust to the bigger screens.

A screenshot would make help make more sense of this.

iPhone 5s
[image]

iPhone 6 Plus
[image]

The Update Me text is one `UILabel`. The Basic to the bottom PRO Unlimited is one `UILabel`. The buttons are separate `UIButton`s. The Restore Purchases is a `UIButton` and the final text on the bottom is a `UILabel`.

The constraints I have in place which matter are:

**Basic Label**

Trailing Space to Superview

Leading Space to Superview

Bottom Space to Restore Purchases `UIButton`

Top Space to UpdateMe `UILabel`

**Buy 100 UIButton**

Leading Space to Superview

Trailing Space to Buy Unlimited `UIButton`

Top Space to Top Layout

Bottom Space to Restore Purchases `UIButton`

Equal Width to Buy Unlimited `UIButton`

**Buy Unlimited `UIButton`**

Trailing Space to Superview

Leading Space to Buy 100

Top Space to Top Layout

Bottom Space to Restore Purchases `UIButton`

Equal Width to Buy 100

**Restore Purchases `UIButton`**

Trailing Space to Superview

Leading Space to Superview

Top Space Basic `UILabel`

Bottom Space to A One Off `UILabel`

Top Space to Buy Unlimited

Top Space to Buy 100

On the iPhone 5s, the Restore Purchases `UIButton` has a width of 268 and height of 30.

On the iPhone 6 Plus, the Restore Purchases `UIButton` has a width of 382 and height of 198, so clearly that's taking up a huge chunk of space which causes the `UIButton` to not increase.

What I would like to achieve is, every component in it's place as it is now, but on the iPhone 6 Plus, have the Buy 100 and Buy Unlimited `UIButton`s to increase in height with the width to stay the same.

Any guidance on this would really be appreciated!

Comment: ++Even if the button size increases It will look odd. You also have to increase the text/label size with increasing screen size.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense! Do you mean font size or actual size of the UILabels? I don't have a height constraint set anywhere, so I'm guessing it should increase with the increase in screen size but don't know if it's doing that right now? If I could make the font size bigger on the bigger screens and simultaneously increase the label size, that could work, but no idea how

Comment: I think both. I myself haven't tried increasing text/label myself. Let's wait for SO community to help. :). But try setting height constraint to each label, so that they can eat space to make layout good.

Comment: Thanks so much for writing in - I appreciate it and I hope the community can help me not go through another day of madness! :)

Comment: check this, [UILabel text not automatically resized using Auto Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157778/uilabel-text-not-automatically-resized-using-auto-layout), Autolayout is done programmatically.

Comment: Thanks very much - that looks real promising! I've not done anything programatically but it does look like it could work

Answer (score 0):

In here you can add Aspect Ratio Constrains to your buttons.

[image]

Comment: Thanks BC, but unfortunately I'm not using images. Just stock UILabels and UIButtons in Xcode; no images

Comment: Then you have to add Aspect Ratio constrains to both UIButtons. Did you try that??

Comment: Thanks BC - that sounds fancy and now I'm looking into what and how to set an Aspect Ratio :)

Comment: Thanks. I've set that up and it is working to some extent, the two buttons are increasing in size which is good, but it's still small and I wonder how to have the buttons increase. The aspect ratio is set to 62:17 for the height

Answer (score 0):

Restore Purchases UIButton:

Remove below constrain

1.Top Space to Buy Unlimited
2.Top Space to Buy 100

Show "preview" the screens in "show assistant editor" option. Check the various screen size using preview option. If needed please remove and add the constraints in your screen. This preview option is very useful to resolve the auto layout constraints issue.

Comment: Thanks Prabakaran - that unfortunately doesn't work and I am using Preview to see the differences in each part

Comment: Hi lavanya, Please remove all dependency in top controls and add dependency in bottom controls and check in preview. Also do some minor adjustment in that constraints. Please refer this tutorials http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2.       Thanks